# Spring Security maximumSessions not working when using custom filter

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Environment:
Spring Boot: 3.2.2.
Spring Security: 6.2.1

I'm currently using a custom filter to support JSON formatted data in requests. I also want to use `maximumSessions` to limit user that can only login in a browser at the same time.

I learned from an article on the internet that it seems necessary to set `ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy` in the custom filter bean. Here is my config code

```
    @Bean
    public LoginFilter loginFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) throws Exception {
        LoginFilter loginFilter = new LoginFilter();
        loginFilter.setFilterProcessesUrl("/doLogin");
        loginFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
        loginFilter.setSecurityContextRepository(new DelegatingSecurityContextRepository(
                new RequestAttributeSecurityContextRepository(),
                new HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository()
        ));
        loginFilter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler((request, response, authentication) -> {
            ...
        });
        loginFilter.setAuthenticationFailureHandler((request, response, exception) -> {
            ...
        });

        ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy strategy = new ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy(sessionRegistry());
        strategy.setMaximumSessions(1);
        loginFilter.setSessionAuthenticationStrategy(strategy);

        return loginFilter;
    }


    @Bean
    public SessionRegistry sessionRegistry() {
        return new SessionRegistryImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    public HttpSessionEventPublisher httpSessionEventPublisher() {
        return new HttpSessionEventPublisher();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity, LoginFilter loginFilter) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
                .sessionManagement(session -> session.maximumSessions(1).maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true))
                .addFilterAt(new ConcurrentSessionFilter(sessionRegistry(), event -> {
                    HttpServletResponse resp = event.getResponse();
                    resp.setContentType("application/json;charset=utf-8");
                    resp.setStatus(401);
                    PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
                    out.write("Already logged in on another device.");
                    out.flush();
                    out.close();
                }), ConcurrentSessionFilter.class)
                .addFilterAt(loginFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .authorizeHttpRequests(
                        requests -> requests
                                .requestMatchers("/css/**", "/js/**", "/images/**", "/getVerifyCode").permitAll()
                                .requestMatchers("/error").permitAll()
                                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )              
                .logout(logout -> logout.logoutUrl("/doLogout")
                        .logoutSuccessHandler((request, response, authentication) -> {
                            ...
                        })
                )
                .csrf(csrfConfigurer -> csrfConfigurer.disable())
                .exceptionHandling(exceptionHandler -> exceptionHandler.authenticationEntryPoint((request, response, authException) -> {
                    log.error(authException);                  
                }));


        return httpSecurity.build();
    }
```

And Here is the code of `LoginFilter`

```
@Log4j2
public class LoginFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {
    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;
    private SessionRegistry sessionRegistry;

    public LoginFilter() {
        super();
        objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setSessionRegistry(SessionRegistry sessionRegistry) {
        this.sessionRegistry = sessionRegistry;
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {
        if (!request.getMethod().equals("POST")) {
            throw new AuthenticationServiceException("Authentication method not supported: " + request.getMethod());
        }

        String verifyCode = (String) request.getSession().getAttribute("verify_code");
        Map<String, String> requestParameters = new HashMap<>();
        if (MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE.equals(request.getContentType())) {
            requestParameters = extractRequestParametersFromJson(request);
        } else {
            requestParameters = extractRequestParametersFromForm(request);
        }

        String code = requestParameters.get("code");
        checkoutVerifyCode(code, verifyCode);

        String username = requestParameters.get(getUsernameParameter());
        String password = requestParameters.get(getPasswordParameter());

        username = username != null ? username.trim() : "";
        password = password != null ? password : "";
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authRequest = UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.unauthenticated(username, password);
        this.setDetails(request, authRequest);

        sessionRegistry.registerNewSession(request.getSession().getId(), authRequest.getPrincipal());
        return this.getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(authRequest);
    }
}
```

I'm new in Spring Security so I'm not sure if the configuration is incorrect or if there are missing parts.
If someone could point out the issue, I would greatly appreciate it.

**Update**

I read the source code and realized that when a user logs in, `ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy#onAuthentication` will be called, and inside this method is `SessionRegistryImpl#getAllSessions`. Inside this method, it will call the `this.principals.get(principal)` method, where `principals` is a `ConcurrentMap<Object, Set<String>>` and `principal` is an `Object` used as the map's key.

The `principal` actually is my custom `User` class and has overridden `equals()` and `hashCode()`. However, the strange thing is that when I set a breakpoint on `equals()`, it shows that the parameter of `equals()` is a `String` object. I am confused as to why the `Map` uses the `User` object as a key but there is a `String` object in `equals()`.

This strange situation only happens when I use my custom filter which extends `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`. If I use the default `HttpSecurity#formLogin` and set the `sessionManagement`, it works normally.

When using `HttpSecurity#formLogin`, the parameter of `equals()` shows the type is `User`. I would like to know what causes the difference from `HttpSecurity#formLogin` and my costom filter.

Answer (score 0):

I have identified the root cause of the problem.

When I get principal by `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` in my `LoginFilter`, the principal is still a String. After the `this.getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(authRequest)` call, the principal will be converted into a `User` object. Consequently, although subsequent operations retrieve a session Set from principals using the principal, the different types cause the incorrect Set to be obtained, resulting in the malfunction of the entire functionality.

Therefore, it is necessary to wait until the principal is converted into a `User` object before allowing the `SessionRegistry` to call `registerNewSession` to store the session in the corresponding principal.

```
    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {
        ...

        Authentication authentication = this.getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(authRequest);
        sessionRegistry.registerNewSession(request.getSession().getId(), authentication.getPrincipal());
        return authentication;
    }
```